# Matrix Calculation Significance and Multivariate Bayesian Methods

Tags: matrices, statistics, probability-distributions, bayesian

Suppose I have the matrix given by:

$$X = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 & 0\\ 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$

This matrix actually represents whether a user interacted with a game on day 1, 2 or 3. The rows are users and days are columns.

Next, we subtract the column means from this matrix:

$$\hat{X} = X - colMean(X) = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -0.66 & -0.33 \\
0 & 0.33 & -0.33 \\ 0 & 0.33 & 0.66 \end{bmatrix}$$

My questions are:

Is there any significance to the product:

$$\hat{X}^TX?$$

The $colMean(X)$ represents the retention rate of the users who interact with my game and the curve produced follows a power law. $X$ also has some covariance matrix, $\Sigma$. Suppose, I gather more information about users and their interaction with my game on the first three days. I would like to use $\mu = colMean(X)$ and the covariance, $\Sigma$, as a prior and then update those parameters with new observations.

How would I go about doing this?

Any comments or references would be greatly appreciated. I just need an idea of where to start. Thank you in advance.

Comment: How do you construct $\Sigma$? What is the significance of $\hat{X}$ in your model? In your construction of $\hat{X}$ you are subtracting numerical variables from indicator variables, seem weird (possible wrong). If you can give an idea of your experimental design it would help. It's hard to figure out what your trying to model, why, and how your trying to measure outcomes.

Comment: @Wintermute - this is coming from a code I am going through - but essentially what it does is standardizes the columns $(\hat{X})$ and then multiplies against $X$, I was just wondering if this has any meaning. As for $\Sigma$ - I have data on a previous segment and $\Sigma$ is a direct calculation of covariance for that data. In the future we will be getting more observations and want to update the mean and covariance from previous data with new data.

Comment: Well you have a binary response variable so my inclination would be to model this using the binomial distribution. Look here for a start http://varianceexplained.org/r/empirical_bayes_baseball/ if your covariance matrix isn't diagonal I would find out what assumptions the person constructing it is making about the relationships between users.

Comment: @Wintermute - thanks for this reference!